# How can I use extension function in c#

Tags: wpf, function

I have a function like this:

```
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
```

Can you explain how I can use this function and what is T?

Comment: http://datagridas2dmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/accesing-wpf-datagrid-rows-and-columns-through-index/

Answer (score 0):

that's an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which is targetted towards a `DependencyObject`. Since it's also a [Generic Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx), it returns an instance of the `T` [Type Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx), which at the same type is [Constrained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to `DependencyObject` and derived types.

Usage example:

```
Window parent = grid.GetVisualParent<Window>();
```

where `grid` can be, for example, a `System.Windows.Controls.Grid`, which is derived from `System.Windows.DependencyObject`, and where the type `Window` is `System.Windows.Window`, which is also derived from `System.Windows.DependencyObject`.

You have a lot of reading to do.